# How to set the focus for a particular field in a Bootstrap modal, once it appears

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I've seen a couple of questions in regards to bootstrap modals, but none exactly like this, so I'll go ahead.

I have a modal that I call onclick like so...

```
$(".modal-link").click(function(event){
  $("#modal-content").modal('show');
});
```

This works fine, but when I show the modal I want to focus on the first input element... In may case the first input element has an id of #photo_name.

So I tried

```
   $(".modal-link").click(function(event){
     $("#modal-content").modal('show');
     $("input#photo_name").focus();
   });
```

But this was to no avail. Lastly, I tried binding to the 'show' event but even so, the input won't focus. Lastly just for testing, as I had a suspiscion this is about the js loading order, I put in a setTimeout just to see if I delay a second, will the focus work, and yes, it works! But this method is obviously crap. Is there some way to have the same effect as below without using a setTimeout?

```
  $("#modal-content").on('show', function(event){
    window.setTimeout(function(){
      $(event.currentTarget).find('input#photo_name').first().focus()
    }, 0500);
  });
```

Answer (score 372, accepted):

Try this

Here is the old [**DEMO**](http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp7x/1/bootstrap%20modal%20focus):

**EDIT:**
(Here is a working [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jlaw/BeL2V/3/) with Bootstrap 3 and jQuery 1.8.3)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#modal-content').modal('show');
    $('#modal-content').on('shown', function() {
        $("#txtname").focus();
    })
});
```

Starting bootstrap 3 need to use shown.bs.modal event:

```
$('#modal-content').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    $("#txtname").focus();
})
```

Comment: Thank you. I had not seen the "shown" event. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: thanks! the demo doesn't working anymore but the snippet does.

Comment: @keyur at codebins.com This event starts after modal is displaying, what if I have to starts event before modal is displayed

Comment: okej, I should use 'show.bs.modal' instead of 'shown.bs.modal'

Comment: about the focus handler, it requires a bit delay so you must but it in a setInterval stuff like this: 
setInterval(function() { $("#your-input").focus(); }, 50);

Comment: I too had to call `focus` after a small delay -- but you'll wont to use *`setTimeout`*, not `setInterval` (as the latter will call your code -- `focus` -- over and over, and your user will not be able to remove focus from that field).

Comment: How to achieve this if there are 5-6 bootstrap modal, I am using this code for first input field(not disabled-hidden-readonly) but its not working...
`$(document).on('shown.bs.modal', function ()
  {
   var firstInput = $(this).find('form:first *:input[type!=hidden]:not(:disabled):not([readonly]):first');
   firstInput.focus();
  });`

Comment: @gaurang171: This shown method gets called in numerous time when I try to show any tool tip on modal.

Answer (score 75):

Just wanted to say that Bootstrap 3 handles this a bit differently. The event name is "shown.bs.modal".

```
$('#themodal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
   $("#txtname").focus();
});
```

or put the focus on the first visible input like this:

```
.modal('show').on('shown.bs.modal', function ()
{
    $('input:visible:first').focus();
})
```

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: It worked for me if I used .on('show.bs.modal') not shown

Comment: It took a lot of time while I saw it should be "shown.bs..." instead of "show.bs...". Show doesnt worked for me. Actually their both are working and they are different events. Sorry ignore my first sentence.

Comment: @PeterGraham maybe you are using bootstrap 2?

Answer (score 10):

I am using this in my layout to capture all modals and focus on the first input

```
  $('.modal').on('shown', function() {
     $(this).find('input').focus();
  });
```

Comment: Sweet. My first input element is hidden though, so I think I would have to do:
$(this).find('input:not([type=hidden])').focus();

Comment: Or `$(this).find('input:visible').focus();`

Comment: should be $(this).find('input').first().focus() if you dont want to focus all inputs

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem with bootstrap 3, focus when i click the link, but not when trigger the event with javascript. 
The solution:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#inputId').focus();
    }, 100);
});
```

Probably it´s something about the animation!

Comment: There is definitely something going on with the modal animation. Even if I turn the modal fade off in the options, it will not render if there is a CPU intensive task right after the modal popup. Using this timeout is the only way I can get it to work.

Answer (score 8):

I had problem to catch "shown.bs.modal" event.. And this is my solution which works perfect..

Instead simple on():

```
$('#modal').on 'shown.bs.modal', ->
```

Use on() with delegated element:

```
$('body').on 'shown.bs.modal', '#modal', ->
```

Answer (score 6):

Seems it is because modal animation is enabled (`fade` in class of the dialog), after calling `.modal('show')`, the dialog is not immediately visible, so it can't get focus at this time.

I can think of two ways to solve this problem:

1. Remove `fade` from class, so the dialog is immediately visible after calling `.modal('show')`. You can see http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp7x/4 for demo. (Sorry @keyur, I mistakenly edited and saved as new version of your example)
2. Call `focus()` in `shown` event like what @keyur wrote.

Comment: Thank you. I wish I could tag two answers as corrent :p. Yes, I didn't even want the "fade" in effect, so removing that works. I removed fade and added the shown event.

Answer (score 4):

I've created a dynamic way to call each event automatically. It perfect to focus a field, because it call the event just once, removing it after use.

```
function modalEvents() {
    var modal = $('#modal');
    var events = ['show', 'shown', 'hide', 'hidden'];

    $(events).each(function (index, event) {
        modal.on(event + '.bs.modal', function (e) {
            var callback = modal.data(event + '-callback');
            if (typeof callback != 'undefined') {
                callback.call();
                modal.removeData(event + '-callback');
            }
        });
    });
}
```

You just need to call `modalEvents()` on document ready.

Use:

```
$('#modal').data('show-callback', function() {
    $("input#photo_name").focus();
});
```

So, you can use the same modal to load what you want without worry about remove events every time.

Comment: That's what I need! Thanks, bro!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with the bootstrap 3 and solved like this:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $(this).find('input[type=text]:visible:first').focus();
})

$('#myModal').modal('show').trigger('shown');
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has added a loaded event.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals

capture the 'loaded.bs.modal' event on the modal

```
$('#mymodal').on('loaded.bs.modal', function(e) {
  // do cool stuff here all day… no need to change bootstrap
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap modal show event

```
$('#modal-content').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
$("#txtname").focus();
```

})

Answer (score -1):

A little cleaner and more modular solution might be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.modal').success(function() { 
        $('input:text:visible:first').focus();
    });  
});
```

Or using your ID as an example instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#modal-content').modal('show').success(function() {
        $('input:text:visible:first').focus();
    });  
});
```

Hope that helps..

Comment: No such function success.