# Calling a function on Bootstrap modal open

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I used to use jQuery UI's dialog, and it had the `open` option, where you can specify some Javascript code to execute once the dialog is opened. I would have used that option to select the text within the dialog using a function I have.

Now I want to do that using bootstrap's modal. Below is the HTMl code:

```
<div id="code" class="modal hide fade">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h3>Modal header</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <pre>
print 'Hello World'
```

And as for the button that opens the modal:

```
 <a href="#code" data-toggle="modal" class="btn code-dialog">Display code</a>
```

I tried to use an onclick listener of the button, but the alert message was displayed *before* the modal appeared:

```
$( ".code-dialog" ).click(function(){
    alert("I want this to appear after the modal has opened!");
});
```

Comment: `shown.bs.modal` event occurs when HTML document contains at least `<div class="modal fade"><div class="modal-dialog"></div></div>` structure.

Comment: dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190119/bootstrap-modal-show-event

Comment: Greet comment @Chemical Programmer, it should appear with the answer

Answer (score 451, accepted):

You can use the [shown event](https://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals)/show event based on what you need:

```
$( "#code" ).on('shown', function(){
    alert("I want this to appear after the modal has opened!");
});
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dawC31?p=preview)

### Update for Bootstrap 3 and 4

For Bootstrap 3.0 and 4.0, you can still use the shown event but you would use it like this:

```
$('#code').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // do something...
})
```

[See the Bootstrap 3.0 docs here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#js-events) under "Events".

Comment: Use `$("#code").on("shown.bs.modal", function(e) {})` for bootstrap 3.0.

Comment: make sure to take into account what Chemical Programmer said about  needing the <div class="modal fade"><div class="modal-dialog"></div></div> structure at least for this code to be called

Comment: The `#code` refers to the jQuery selector, one of the basic ingredients for jQuery: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp

Comment: I use `$(document).on("shown.bs.modal", ...` for overall listening

Comment: @Xatenev `show` is at the beginning of the event, `shown` is at the end. This is consistent across Bootstrap 3 and 4

Comment: The Bootstrap 3.0 works for me, but I get the alert first and the modal afterwards. Not that it matters in my case.

Comment: At least the shown.bs.modal actually executes before the modal is shown. This is not a problem in my case, but may be good to know.

Comment: @vladkras Thank you, that was exactly what I needed to do to overcome a set of restrictions that was tying my hands. You helped bring several days of suffering to an end just like that. Appreciated.

Answer (score 117):

will not work.. use `$(window)` instead

#### For Showing

```
$(window).on('shown.bs.modal', function() { 
    $('#code').modal('show');
    alert('shown');
});
```

#### For Hiding

```
$(window).on('hidden.bs.modal', function() { 
    $('#code').modal('hide');
    alert('hidden');
});
```

Comment: $( "#modal" ).on('shown', function(){  alert("I want this to appear after the modal has opened!");} Was not working for me but $(window) worked !! Thanks @viper_tkd

Comment: I needed to bind to *ANY* modal that opened/closed, and not by a specific selector. This answer worked well for me in that case.

Comment: This works before modal is fully loaded on GUI. I want to take data from my modal after modal is loaded - this method returns 'undefined' for everything because modal GUI is not yet existing, so fields and everything else is not queryable yet. (not visible)

Comment: This worked for me, but I added a check within the handler to target one specific modal: `if( $('#code').is( e.relatedTarget ) ) { ... }` since I had multiple on the page.

Comment: Thanks for the correct event name, but, there is no need to replace the element ID  for $(window). Using bs4 with jquery 3.4.

Comment: with update to get specific modal in my bootstrap version was:        
    `if (shownEvent.target.id == 'uploadTemplateModal'){ }`

Answer (score 35):

you can use `show` instead of `shown` for making the function to load just before modal open, instead of after modal open.

```
$('#code').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // do something...
})
```

Answer (score 11):

Bootstrap modal exposes events. Listen for the the `shown` event like this

```
$('#my-modal').on('shown', function(){
  // code here
});
```

Comment: Replace `shown` with `shown.bs.modal` if using Bootstrap > 3

Answer (score 4):

This what worked with me to target specifec modal

```
$('#code').on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
  // code here
  alert('shown13');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if somebody still has a problem the only thing working perfectly for me by useing (loaded.bs.modal) :

```
 $('#editModal').on('loaded.bs.modal', function () {
       console.log('edit modal loaded');

       $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            clearBtn: true,
            rtl: false,
            todayHighlight: true,
            toggleActive: true,
            changeYear: true,
            changeMonth: true
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### With bootstrap 5

You can open the modal programmatically and simply call your method afterwards, so:

```
const modal = new bootstrap.Modal('#myModal')
modal.show()
alert('modal is showing')
```

Comment: Here you manually trigger the modal and fire off another manual alert.  The original question wanted an event when the modal was shown programmatically.   Bootstrap 5 would require binding with the shown event for the modal.


myModalEl.addEventListener('shown.bs.modal', event => {})


https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/modal/

Comment: @WiseGuy Thanks for the response. You're right, but at least for my case the effect was the same, so I'm leaving it, as it might help others as well.