# Make jquery ajax request after Bootstrap modal has opened

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap 3.3.7 modal (`#calendarModal`) being opened when an `<a>` tag is clicked:

```
<a style="display:block" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#calendarModal">
```

I want to make a jquery ajax request when the modal has opened.

I've taken a look at https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/5169 but binding won't work. For example the link suggests:

```
$('#calendarModal').bind('load', function() { /* do something cool */ });
```

That doesn't work. If I use `console.log` inside the function to test it, it doesn't seem to fire.

How can this be done? I realise I could target the click on the anchor but I'd prefer to know how to do it when the modal is loaded?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a function on bootstrap modal open](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17461682/calling-a-function-on-bootstrap-modal-open)

Comment: @ADyson agreed, the answer is within that post. `$('#calendarModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {`

Comment: Within the shown.bs.modal function, just put your ajax code there.