# How can I call a function when a Bootstrap modal is open?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal, laravel-blade

I use Boostrap 3.7 and Blade (Laravel 5.5).

I'm trying to display `console.log('works')` when my boostrap modal opens but it didn't work.

**HTML :**

```
@foreach(...)

    ...

    <div class="modal fade" id="reservationModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="reservationModal" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

**JS :**

```
$('#reservationModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    console.log('works');
});
```

I followed this doc : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals

And I already read that : [Calling a function on bootstrap modal open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17461682/calling-a-function-on-bootstrap-modal-open)

Thank's for help !

**EDIT 1:**

I solved the problem with this code :

```
$(document).on('show.bs.modal', '#reservationModal', function (e) {
    console.log('works');
});
```

But how to differenciate modals (because they are into `foreach` loop)?

Something like :

```
$(document).on('show.bs.modal', '#reservationModal-specificId', function (e) {
    console.log('works');
});
```

Comment: You're using the right event, however it looks like you're duplicating the `reservationModal` id multiple times as you're creating that element in a loop. That's likely to be the cause of your problem

Comment: where have you written this JS code? is it after the modal created?

Comment: @FarazPV I think not because JS file is called on the `<head></head>`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan and how can I solved this ? With an id on the `id='reservationModal'` like `id='reservationModal-3'` ? But if do this, how detect that it's the modal 3 or modal 6 which is open ?

Comment: give this code after @endforeach

Comment: $('#reservationModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    console.log('works');
});

Comment: Maybe you are adding the event listener before HTML printing.

Comment: @N.Lamblin Don't use incremental `id` attributes. Use a `class` instead.

Comment: Bootstrap modal have an opend function i guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your event listeners are created before HTML printing.
So try this code.

```
$(document).on('show.bs.modal', '#reservationModal', function (e) {
    console.log('works');
});
```

$(document).on('show.bs.modal', **'#reservationModal'**, function (e) {});

the bold characters will help to identify your modal

**ANSWER FOR YOUR UPDATED PART**

run the loop and create your modal as follows

```
<div class="modal fade reservationModal" id="reservationModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="reservationModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        ...
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade reservationModal" id="reservationModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="reservationModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
...... and so on
```

Give reservationModal as class

and id as an incremented value appended to it

```
$(document).on('show.bs.modal', '.reservationModal', function (e) {
    console.log($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Comment: Yes my event are created before because JS is created in `<head></head>`. That's works but how know which modal is call ?

Comment: i have given reservationModal as id

Comment: $(document).on('show.bs.modal', '#reservationModal'

Comment: Yes but my code is into `@foreach()` so each modal are same id right ? Ho differentiate them ...

Comment: are you getting the console or not?

Comment: your question was that you are not getting the console.log, and I have provided you the answer

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @Rory McCrossan in a comment, the duplication of the id is the key problem of your code. To fix this, you may use index:

```
id="reservationModal-{{$loop->index}}"
```

And use start with selector like this if you want to call on each modal:

```
$('[id^="reservationModal-"]').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    console.log('works');
});
```

Or, just use indexed selector to use on particular modal:

```
$('#reservationModal-3').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    console.log('works');
});
```

Comment: My objective is to have a generic code for each modal yes. But your solution with `$('[id^="reservationModal-"]')` and`{{$loop->index}}` seems didn't works because modal didn't open at all.

Comment: I think that the first solution, with `[id^="reservationModal-"]` is the right way but didn't works and i don't know why.