# Bootstrap Modal Show Event not intercepted with any event listeners

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/egx5moL8/).

I have Bootstrap Modals as in this example, and I need to intercept their **Open/Show** event. But none of the suggestions mentioned in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17461682/calling-a-function-on-bootstrap-modal-open/17461707) work  for me. Am I missing something?

I tried the following:

```
// Listener - Show Event Interception

    // NONE OF THE FOLLOWING WORK
        $('#modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
            alert('Modal opened 1');
        });
        $('#modal').on('shown', function (e) {
            alert('Modal opened 2');
        });  
      $(window).on('shown.bs.modal', function() { 
          alert('Modal opened 3');
        });
```

My Modal looks like this (opened with `$('#modal').show();`):

```
<div class="modal modal-dialog" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  aria-hidden="true" >  
  <div class="modal-content" style="margin:0 auto;">
     ...
  </div>
</div>
```

### Update

The immediate problem is that I'm using `show()` rather than `modal('show')`. However I also tried to intercept using `$(document).on('show', function(evt) {..}` and failed.

New approach just to intercept a jQuery `show()` event:

```
$(document).on('show', function(evt) {
    if($(evt.target).attr('role') != null && $(evt.target).attr('role') == 'dialog') { 
       alert('Intercepted Dialog Show'); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fiddle shows the modal via jQuery's `.show` method which essentially makes a hidden element visible. Therefore no events will trigger.

To trigger the `shown.bs.modal` event, and any event related to the modal for that matter, you'll want to use the modal methods particularly `.modal('show')` to show the modal accordingly.

```
$('#opendlg').click(function() {
    $('#modal').modal('show');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know why I can't intercept as `$(document).on('show', function(evt) {...}`? I tried that as well just to intercept `show` and I couldn't. I will update the Fiddle with an exampe.

Comment: The correct event when binding to document is `$(document).on('show.bs.modal', '#modal', function(evt) { ... })`