# Calling a function on bootstrap modal open - js additional code

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

> its not dublicated question because I didnt understand the smilar
> question's answer.may I can delete after solved my question, if the answer so easy.

When bootstrap 3 modal is opened, my mega menu appear upon it.to solve this, while bootstrap modals are opened, I must reduce z-index of mega menu.mega menu's z-index is maximum now for all time.

I found this question:

[Calling a function on bootstrap modal open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17461682/calling-a-function-on-bootstrap-modal-open/17461707)

it says:

```
$('#code').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // do something...
})
```

for bootstap 3.

how can I write this code with jquery or javasicript?

> **edit: to give specific request, I want to determine bootstrap class to use it instead of #code word and then, write changing z-index value of a spesific class via jquery.**

https://resimli.yedek.deniz-tasarim.site/

website is this.

bootstrap modals open with sign up/login buttons on header. ( top-right )

---

I am foreign to bootstap 3 and there are many classes for modals.So, it confused me.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you specifically explain what exactly you want to achieve ?!

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov I editted question.in spesfical perspective, " to give specific request, I want to determine bootstrap class to use it instead of #code word and then, write changing z-index value of a spesific class via jquery. "

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov can you look the question again please?

Comment: hi. yes, of course, only a little later.

Comment: Is your problem still relevant at the moment?

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov unfortunately, yes

Comment: Now I understand your problem. Write the name of the modal (class or id). I know how to adjust the z-index in jquery.

Comment: id is #signin . I hope this work

Comment: Are you getting an alert message for this code? - `$('#signin').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) { window.alert("eski uyarı"); });`

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov I think this question also need bootstrap 3 js information because it doesnt work.probably I putted signin id to wrong place in php code.I converted html code to wordpress theme but my bootstrap info is weak

Comment: Is this your problem? - https://ibb.co/j8LXhXC

Comment: yes, exactly it is

Comment: It can be solved by css. Without javascript and jquery.

Comment: how to? I gave maximum z-index for both of them.

Comment: The mega menu has the maximum index by default, and it seems to me not entirely correct. Now I will give you a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your menu overlaps the modal due to the default maximum `z-index`.

Here's what the css rules for the menu look like now:

```
#wp-megamenu-header-menu {
    z-index: 9999; <=== /*the problem is here*/
    text-align: left;
    height: 90px;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-right: -20px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

And this is most likely written by you:

```
.wp-megamenu-wrap {
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

To solve this problem, it is sufficient to override the `z-index` with the `!important` rule. Insert this rule into your css:

```
#wp-megamenu-header-menu {
    z-index: 1000!important;
}
```

And your overlap problem will go away!