# Show Bootstrap modal on hover

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, magento, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to display a Bootstrap Modal on my webshop when the mouse hovers over a product. I searched online and found the following:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12190456/3164891

I got it to work in the Fiddle by adding the following code:

```
$('#openBtn').hover(function () {
    $('#modal-content').modal({
        show: true
    });
});
```

But when I want to apply it to my situation I can't get it to work
**HTML**

```
<li class="item">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-trigger="hover" data-target="#basicModal-<?php echo  $_product->getId()?>" class="product-image" id="<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>">   
        <img id="product-collection-image-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($_imgSize); ?>" />
    </a>
</li>

<div class="modal fade" id="basicModal-<?php echo $_product->getID()?>" role="dialog"  aria-hidden="true" data-trigger="hover">
    <div class="modal-content">
         Modal Content
    </div>
</div>
```

**Calling the modal**

```
jQuery('.item').hover(function () {
    jQuery('#basicModal').modal({
        show: true
    });
});
```

When I try it on my site the modal only shows when the a href is clicked and does nothing on hover. I've also tried the following code:

```
jQuery('#basicModal').modal({trigger: "hover"});
```

I'm using the following versions:

- jQuery: 1.10.2.min
- Bootstrap: 3.2.0

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to modal `id="basicModal"` but you're adding id to it.

Comment: try `jQuery('.modal')` instead of `jQuery('#basicModal')`, to use this method, just make sure that you dont have more than one modal in a page.

Comment: I have tried it but feel strange that ' $("#mymodal").modal("show") '    is not firing on mouseover or any hover event.I will suggest,go for [popover](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers)

Answer (score 3):

Your javascript code that is firing the modal on hover, it's not selecting the right element:

```
jQuery('#basicModal')
```

In the above line you are selecting an element with id === "basicModal", but in your html the id is equal to `basicModal-<?php echo $_product->getID()?>`. The two id strings must match, or you can use a jquery wildcard, like `JQuery("[id^=basicModal]")` that selects all elements with id sarting with basicModal.

Here is a working version of your code with the wildcard solution: http://jsfiddle.net/fcyafcgx/