# bootsprap 2.1 modal autofocus not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

> ISSUE : Auto focus is not applying to my pop up form of bootstrap 2.1

I am using twitter **bootstrap 2.1** trying to autofocus on first input element when click and a pop up is show.

I need guidance to resolve this issue. I have try with JavaScript **focus** function and also try with html autofocus property but it is not applying.

[Bootstrap modal show event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190119/bootstrap-modal-show-event)

I tried this stack overflow question but it require to update my bootstrap to 3.0 but it is not possible for me to update as it require huge time.

I want similar autofocus with bootstrap 2.1 please guide me towards this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share some code to show what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this...

Bootstarp model have "shown" event. It fires after model open. Just put your code for focus first element of form on the event function. Like below

```
$('your-model-id').on('shown', function () {
  $('#your-text-box-id').focus();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**its general solutions for all used modal no need to write method for individual modal you can try this**

```
$('.modal').on('shown', function () {
        var first_elemt = $('.modal').filter(':visible:first').find('input[type=text]').attr('id');
       $('#'+first_elemt).focus();
     });
```