# Display slider correctly in bs modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I use bootstrap modal + slick slider for show slider in bs modal window, but have some problem with display this.
Slider not open before autoplay does
[not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxp00.png)

But [i need this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pCpz.jpg) right away modal be loaded

Here js code

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

    $(".mwrap").on("click", function() {
        var img, desc, value, elements;
        img = $("img", this).attr("src");
        desc = $("p", this).html();
        value = $("img", this).data("value");

        elements = $.map($('img[data-value="' + value + '"]'), function(img) {
            return $("<div/>", {
                html: $(img).clone()
            })
        })

        $(".wimg").attr("src", img);
        $(".wdesc").html(desc);
        $(".wslider").html(elements)
        $(".wslider").slick({
            dots: true,
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            autoplay: true
        });
    });

    $("#myModal").on("hide.bs.modal", function() {
        $(".wslider").slick('destroy').html("");
    })

});
```

Thanks!

Comment: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12190456/6501094) to possible solution. Use a modal shown event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `$.slick()` from `shown.bs.modal` event

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".mwrap").on("click", function() {
        var img, desc, value, elements;
        img = $("img", this).attr("src");
        desc = $("p", this).html();
        value = $("img", this).data("value");

        elements = $.map($('img[data-value="' + value + '"]'), function(img) {
            return $("<div/>", {
                html: $(img).clone()
            })
        })

        $(".wimg").attr("src", img);
        $(".wdesc").html(desc);
        $(".wslider").html(elements)

    });

    $("#myModal").on("shown.bs.modal", function() {
        $(".wslider").slick({
            dots: true,
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            autoplay: true
        });
    });

    $("#myModal").on("hide.bs.modal", function() {
        $(".wslider").slick('destroy').html("");
    });

});
```