# Pass ID from AJAX to PHP back to Modal

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP CODE:

```
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['id']);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `tb_cform` WHERE `ID`='$id'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $message = '<div><h4>Subject: </h4><h5>'.$row['subj'].'<h5></div>';
        $message .= '<hr><br>';
        $message .= '<div><b>Message:<br>'.$row['message'].'</b></div>';
    }

    echo $message;
}
```

I need to pass the value from my AJAX code to the aforementioned code:

```
$('#messageModal').on('show', function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "viewmessage.php",
        datatype: "html",
        data:"data-id=" +id  , 
        success: function(r){
            $('#messageBody').html( r );
        }
    });
});
```

The link that I am using is using a `data-id="73"` to pop open a model and populate the information.

My issue is, the value is not being passed and the body of the Modal is not being populated. Can anyone let me know why or what I did incorrect?

Comment: Side note: the first line of your `while()` will overwrite itself on every iteration. You need to have `$message = '';` above the `while()`, then the first line then needs `$message .=` not just `$message =`

Comment: Although there will only be one iteration with your query, so you probably should just fetch the array and not do the `while()` at all. Also, if you are not binding parameters on `$id`, you should then first check if it's numeric (presumably it's supposed to be numeric?).

Comment: @Rasclatt , Yes it is numeric.  I can pass the `is_numeric($_POST['id'])` parameter in there as well.  I just want to see if it will populate the results and its not.

Answer (score 1):

Check that your db returns something, so that `$result` is not null. Otherwise your `$message` will be empty.
If your query actually returns something and `$message` is still empty - try changing datatype to json:

JS

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'php/server.php',
    datatype: 'JSON',
    data: {
        dataId: someArbitraryId
    },
    success: function(data) {
        var message = JSON.parse(data).message;
        $('#message').html(message);
    }
});
```

PHP

```
if (isset($_POST['dataId'])) {
    $message = '';

    // Some code 

    $result = array(
        'message' => $message
    );

    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Now even if the `$message` is empty or null - server should return array with empty string.

Comment: Just want to leave a thank you since I have been looking over more then a dozen SO questions and answers and none of them came as close to immediately working as yours did. So thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

in js

```
data:{dataId : id}, // I'm sure this will work but data:"data-id=" +id, may work as well
```

in php

```
$_POST['dataId'] // instead of $_POST['id']
```

***If this not work with you there are some steps you need to do***

1- `alert(r)` on ajax success function and check for errors

2- I don't know what is `id` and where you get it from so try to `alert(id)` and see if it output an expected value or not

3- you may need to use `shown.bs.modal` instead of `show` take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12190456/3385827)

4- in js try to get the `a data-id` by using `$(a[data-target="#messageModal"]).data('id')` instead of `id`

so your code should looks like

in js

```
$('#messageModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "viewmessage.php",
        datatype: "html",
        data:{ dataId : $(a[data-target="#messageModal"]).data('id')}, 
        success: function(r){
            $('#messageBody').html( r );
        }
    });
});
```

and also in php use `$_POST['dataId']` instead of `$_POST['id']`

Comment: maybe your id is blank in the first place?

Comment: @PKershner I updated my answer with the steps you should do if its still not working

Comment: are you not reinitializing the var id in anyway? the above should work maybe it goes wrong somewhere else..

Comment: BTW @guradio congratulations for +10K rep ..you're a good programmer ..  keep it up :-)

Comment: the alerts are not showing. So I think my ajax function is broken or my link.

Comment: this is in my foreach loop 
`<td><a href="#" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-id="'.$values['ID'].'" data-target="#messageModal">View</a></td>
  </tr>';` to populate the link for each message that is in the DB.

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef thank you mate you helped me alot before youre one of the best here :)

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef, here is what I have:

`data: {data-id : $(a[data-target="#messageModal"]).data("id")},` but it seems to be throwing an error.  its saying "Expected ':' and instead saw '-' "

Comment: @PKershner this my first time using `-` on ajax post may it cause a problem .. so you can change `data-id` to `dataId` .. I updated my answer

Comment: Still nothing showing.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  I have everything set the way you said to do, but its not populating in the messageBody like it states.  Instead of using data-id, is there any other way of passing the variable like a hidden input field?

Answer (score 0):

So i figured out the issue, it is now displaying the results, however, `$(a[data-target="#messageModal"]).data('id');` will not pass the value, i had to use: `var id = $("#messageID").attr("data-id");`.  This is working, but becuase there are multiple instances of #messageID listed, it is only showing the first result becuase you cannot have duplicate ID tags with the same information.  
​
My question is how can i assign or get a value added after #messageID like an array using[ ] to assign a value and have it look for that then get the data-id value to pass?