# Autofocus on editable gridview field

Tags: gridview, yii2, editablegrid

How can I add the autofocus and select on the editable gridview field?

I want to make editacle field autofocus and autoselect.
Here's my gridview code :

```
<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        'filterModel'=>$searchModel,
        'showPageSummary'=>true,
        'pjax'=>true,
        'striped'=>true,
        'hover'=>true,
        'responsiveWrap' => false,
        'panel'=>['type'=>'primary', 'heading'=>$partner_name],
        'columns'=>[
            [
                'attribute' => 'city_code',
                'label' => 'City Code',
            ],
            [
                'class'=>'kartik\grid\EditableColumn',
                'editableOptions'=>[
                   'asPopover' => false,
                   'inputType'=>\kartik\editable\Editable::INPUT_TEXT,
                ],

                'attribute'=>'amount',
                'label'=>'Amount',

            ],
        ],
    ]);

    ?>
<?php Pjax::end() ; ?>
```

Comment: post your gridview code here

Comment: @SardorDushamov, I've added my gridview code on my question, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As kartik mentions [here](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-editable/issues/117), the Editable widget doesn't give any APIs for focus; you need to do this in javascript.

So, you need to find the popover modal's id (by default, it's called something like "`<modelname>-<rowid>-<attributename>-popover`"), and declare that after it is shown, the display inside ("`<modelname>-<rowid>-<attributename>-disp`") needs to be selected.

So, something like

```
<?php
  $this->registerAssetBundle(yii\web\JqueryAsset::className(), \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD); // in case you don't have jQuery set
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  for (rowid=0; rowid<10; row++) { // or some other form of iterating over your rows
    popover_id = "#city-" + rowid + "-amount-popover";  // replace city and amount with your model name and your attribute name
    $(popover_id).on('shown.bs.modal', function(event) {
      // setTimeout(function() {
      display_id = "#"+event.target.id.replace(/popover$/,'disp');
      $(display_id).select();
      // }, 10);
    });
  }
});
</script>
```

Note that there are two commented lines that wrap the `select()` call inside a timeout.  Depending on your system, it might [take some time between the display of the popover and the instantiation of the display (so you can focus and select on it)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190119/bootstrap-modal-show-event). If that's the case, you'll need to uncomment those lines.

Comment: You need to look at the DOM that is being generated and figure out what the ids on your rows are.

Comment: okey i got it, i've found that my row ids are `data-key` but it's still doesn't work. What should i do then?

Comment: Is `"#city-" + rowid + "-amount-popover"` generating the correct ids for your popover tags?  Search inside your DOM and see if you have ids called `city-1-amount-popover`, `city-2-amount-popover`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this JS code:

```
$("form input:text, form textarea").first().focus();
```